# Is the bias of a coin a latent variable or a parameter?

Tags: terminology, latent-variable

Consider the standard Bayesian estimation problem in which the bias $p$ of a coin is picked uniformly at random from $[0, 1]$, the coin is tossed a few times, and $p$ is then estimated from the outcomes.

In such a case, is $p$ a parameter or a latent variable? It is "fixed", in the sense that it is a single number and doesn't change throughout the problem, but I can also see it as a random variable since it has a prior uniform probability distribution, so I don't know what to call it...

Comment: Could you explain the basis of your concern about the distinction? It seems that whatever terminology you adopt, you wind up with exactly the same model.

Comment: @whuber: I'm just trying to understand the proper terminology in the literature...

Comment: The whole point of Bayesian modeling is that this distinction doesn't exist.

Comment: @ssdecontrol: I see. Please post that as an answer!

Comment: @Mehrdad I'll write something up tomorrow